# MotionEvent GetY() and getX() return incorrect values

Tags: android, coordinates, motion

I have following situation:

I have a custom ListView with ImageView and TextView in a row.
The ImageView has an onTouchListener, wchich invokes my onTouch method. Here are some lines from it:

```
if (event.getAction()==MotionEvent.ACTION_MOVE) {
    layout.leftMargin = (int) event.getX() - dragIcon.getWidth()/2;         
    layout.topMargin = (int) event.getY() - dragIcon.getHeight()/2;
    //Log.d("Tag", "Pozycja: " +  event.getX() +", "+  event.getY());
}
dragIcon.setLayoutParams(layout);
```

When move is detected I'm showing up new image (not this in ListView) and I'm starting to move it according to x and y coordinates.

The problem is, that getX and getY return positions relative to ImageView in the list, not the whole ListView (I think so). So when I touch an item in the middle and swipe finger up, then getY returns negative values (above ImageView boundary).

Hope, I explained clearly..

Any ideas how to get this coordinates relative to the screen size?
Thank you.

Comment: See also [Difference between MotionEvent.getRawX and MotionEvent.getX](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/20636163/difference-between-motionevent-getrawx-and-motionevent-getx)

Answer (score 49, accepted):

Try using `getRawX()` and `getRawY()` instead of `getX()` and `getY()`.

Comment: in my case both y and rawY are incorrect for cancel motion event in onTouchListener in ViewHolder in recycleview with simpleselection.

Answer (score 6):

getX() and getY() returns the values respective to the views that it was called on. 
Hence 
Let's say,

```
ImageView imV = (ImageView)findViewById(R.id.image_view);
```

Then you can get x,y using

```
x = imV.getX() + event.getX();
y = imV.getY() + event.getY();
```

Here I assume you have set the onTouchListener on imV.

Comment: You saved me. This works great. getRawX(), getRawY() didn't helped me.

Answer (score 0):

Here's the full answer. This captures the last 3 events on a temporary variable: https://stackoverflow.com/a/54438485/1931228