# Difference between MotionEvent.getRawX and MotionEvent.getX

Tags: android-layout, android

I would like to know The difference between `MotionEvent.getRawX` and `MotionEvent.getX` in android as one is numeric and the other is float?Whats the need to have both of these types?

Answer (score 64):

[image: Picture for easy understanding]

=>

```
rawX = motionEvent.getX() + touchableButton.getX() + layout3.getX() + layout2.getX();
```