# Difference between event.getX() and event.getRawX()

Tags: android, android-canvas

What is main difference between  `event.getX()` and `event.getRawX()` .In which scenario `event.getRawX()` used .can any one explain with detail ?

Comment: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/20636163/difference-between-motionevent-getrawx-and-motionevent-getx

Comment: That other question has no text in the answer. This one is much more helpful.

Answer (score 5):

The link below will give you the difference between them:

[Difference between MotionEvent.getRawX and MotionEvent.getX](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/20636163/difference-between-motionevent-getrawx-and-motionevent-getx)

To know the scenarios when each of them is used:

Android touch events can be used for simple gestures like left, right swipe and can even be used complex touch scenarios like designing games. Now for simple swipe events we don't need all the raw values. Just the touch coordinates relative to our view are enough. But in gaming and other complex scenarios, we are not sure how we may need to used the touch coordinates values. So, we take raw values from system and manipulate them accordingly. Their can be few other similar scenarios where those APIs can be used accordingly.

Answer (score 4):

This means that in practice getX() and getY() are useless for many use cases, and you should base your application logic on getRawX() and getRawY() that is guaranteed to return absolute coordinates, relative to the device screen. When using the MapView, I was able to get the relative X and Y coordinates by subtracting the View.getLeft() and View.getTop() of the Window's content view (Window.ID_ANDROID_CONTENT) from the MotionEvent.getRawX() and MotionEvent.getRawY(), respectively.

Comment: Not for future readers: getRawX() does not work as expected when the layout is scaled.